# When and by "whom" is the Dispose() method called after scenario

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I use SpecFlow.NUnit.
Let's say I have 2 scenarios and I run them

Scenario: First
Given Definition1

Scenario: Second
Given Definition2

```
[Given (@"Definition1")]
public void Definition1{
  File.Open(@"C:\Users\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
}

[Given (@"Definition2")]
public void Definition2{
  File.Open(@"C:\Users\1.txt", FileMode.Open); // no error thrown
}
```

I am trying to undertand how is that that after the "First" scenario runs and opens a FileStream and method `Definition1()` does NOT close it, no error is thrown when the "Second" scenario opens a FileStream on the same file.
This leads me into thinking that sdomewhere the Dispose(); is called, but where and by whom?
maybe this is not a specflow thing but NUnit thing?

Comment: In this case, you have 2 completely separate handles open to the same file.  You don't have any code that closes the handle, so the handle remains used (and taking up memory) until the garbage collector gets called.  The test should be disposing of the handle, either by a `using` or by calling dispose manually.

Comment: Nothing disposes the streams explicitly. Both streams are orphaned and will be disposed when the garbage collector runs. Perhaps NUnit calls GC.Collect explicitly after each test? In any case, this code leaks 2 stream objects.

Comment: @Neil: No, Eric is correct to note that there's something odd going on here that needs explanation. The default for File.Open is to open a file *exclusively*, and it should produce a "the process cannot access the file" error on the second attempt unless something has closed the file. There are not two handles open; there is at most one. Something has closed the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer but I have some informed speculation.

You are correct that *something* is closing the file between the first and second opens; the default sharing mode for File.Open is "no sharing even in the same process", and you should therefore get the (confusing and wrong) error message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."  (The error message should say the truth: "The file cannot be opened because it is already opened for exclusive access".)

What then is closing the file? First, understand how finalization works in C#.

- The correct thing to do is to call `Dispose` or otherwise close the file. A correct implementation of `Dispose` will close the file and mark the object as not requiring finalization. The finalizer thread then never sees the object.
- The incorrect thing to do is to skip closing/disposing. Eventually the garbage collector will run and notice that an object which requires finalization is dead. That gets put onto a queue, and the finalizer thread eventually executes the finalizer, closing the file.

Since you are not disposing of the file, something must be closing it. I can think of four possibilities; there may be others.

(1) You are getting lucky (or unlucky, depending on your point of view) and the garbage collector is happening to run, finding the orphaned file, putting it on the finalizer queue, and the finalizer runs before the second attempt to open the file.

(2) Your test framework is calling `GC.Collect` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` between tests, forcing the resources to be cleaned up.

(3) Your test framework is putting each test into an `AppDomain` and unloading the `AppDomain` between tests. That should also force resources to be cleaned up.

(4) Your test framework is running each test in a separate process. Exclusive locks on files do not survive process termination.

Without knowing the details of how NUnit works, I couldn't tell you which of the above scenarios you're in, but you're likely in one of them.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if there is even a difference between running the tests using `dotnet test`, `nunit-console.exe` and the Visual Studio test runner. The process that initiates the tests could also play a role on top of the test framework itself, because test runners can keep processes in memory to reduce spin-up time. @EricMovsessian, not cleaning up disposable object leads you down some dark and twisted alleys, as you've found out.

Comment: okay, thank you very much, this was very intereting also in that I had to do a lot of research based on the answer

Answer (score 1):

While my answer won't explain *why* this happens, it should explain how to fix it within the realm of SpecFlow, rendering this question moot.

SpecFlow comes with its own dependency injection container, which will dispose of objects at the end of a scenario as long as they implement `IDisposable`. Step definition classes are automatically registered in the SpecFlow DI container.

In this case, you have some file handles to clean up. Assuming this file handle is only used in one step definition file, the solution is to assign the `FileStream` object returned by `File.Open` to a field, which is then disposed of. The step definition class needs to implement `IDisposable` in order to do this:

```
[Binding]
public class YourSteps : IDisposable
{ //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    private FileStream oneDotTxtFile;

    private FileStream OneDotTxtFile
    {
        if (oneDotTxtFile == null)
        {
            oneDotTxtFile = File.Open(@"C:\Users\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
        }

        return oneDotTxtFile;
    }

    [Given(@"Definition1")]
    public void Definition1()
    {
        OneDotTxtFile.WhateverYouNeedToDoWithIt();
    }

    [Given(@"Definition2")]
    public void Definition2()
    {
        OneDotTxtFile.WhateverYouNeedToDoWithIt();
    }

    #region Implement Dispose Pattern found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (oneDotTxtFile != null)
                {
                    oneDotTxtFile.Dispose();
                    oneDotTxtFile = null;
                }
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that adding `: IDisposable` to your step definition class declaration is necessary. Visual Studio gives you a Quick Action to implement the Dispose pattern if you right-click on the IDisposable interface name in your code. This stubs out the boilerplate code to implement this interface according to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

Now you can simply use the FileStream without thinking about it. The OneDotTxtFile property will lazily open the file the first time you call the property. The `Dispose()` method in the step definition class is invoked by the SpecFlow DI container at the end of each scenario, which will dispose of the FileStream object if the field is not null.

Comment: Thank you very much Greg. I have checked all the materials you have provided and a little more so I understand the code you provided and I see that thsi way we are letting speclfow to call Dispose(true); So obviously my production code does not look like this, the code in the question was just for the question, but I am wondering wouldn't it be still okay to just call the Dispose method on the FileStream object returned by File.Open(..), after the work with the stream is done?

Comment: @EricMovsessian: yes, see [using statement - ensure the correct use of disposable objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) for more information.

Comment: There is a specific C# language feature you should be using to ensure this happens properly.